# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)'
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.AddHasCasting.getAdditionalCommands(AddHasCasting.java:38)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.getExtraCommands(ChromeDriver.java:99)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.(ChromeDriver.java:94)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:82)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:50)
at Task.main(Task.java:18)

Code:

public class PlaytechAutomationTest {
private WebDriver driver;

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    // Setting system property for Chrome browser
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path");

    // Creating a ChromeDriver instance
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

@Test
public void testInternshipPosition() throws InterruptedException {
    // Navigating to Playtech website
    driver.get("https://www.playtech.ee");

    // Clicking on the internship tab using coordinates
    WebElement internTab = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='menu-main-menu']//li[5]//a"));
    int x = internTab.getLocation().getX();
    int y = internTab.getLocation().getY();
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(internTab).moveByOffset(x, y).click().perform();
```

How to solve it?
The problem is somewhere in the "Clicking on the internship tab using coordinates"part

Comment: can you add more code, its had to understand the problem from just the errors

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.